# How to make multiple lists with a loop in Java?

Tags: java, list, loops

So I would like to create multiple lists that have similar but different names.

So far I have:

```
for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
        String listName = String.format("listNumber%d", i);
        int[] listName;
    }
```

How can I change the third line so I would get listNumber1, listNumber2 etc

Comment: You want to change the variable name? Variable names cannot be changed programmatically and are there for readability.

Comment: Either make them into an array so you get listName[0], listName[1] etc. or make a list of lists. There is no way to dynamically generate a set of variable names.

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can't. You could create a map containing your arrays:

```
Map<String, int[]> listMap = new HashMap<>();

for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
    String listName = String.format("listNumber%d", i);
    listMap.put(listName, new int[arraySize]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use String on a variable name in Java.

If you want to use String to access a List, you can use Map;

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> lists = new HashMap<>();
lists.put("listNumber1", new ArrayList<Integer>());
lists.put("listNumber2", new ArrayList<Integer>());

lists.get("listNumber1").add(1);
```

But if you use String to itarate the lists, you can use array of List or List of List;

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
lists.add(new ArrayList<>());
lists.add(new ArrayList<>());

for(List<Integer> list : lists) {
    list.add(1);
}
```